# Codeigniter: "Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference" error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to get some data from a mysql database and show it in a listview on mobile site,

Code runs fine but it throw this error:
`Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference C:\AppServ\www\system\core\Loader.php on line 150`

Below is the excerpt of code:
`$this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();`

but the date come as `undefined` into the listview!

I didn't have this problem at first? So, what shall i do to over come this error?!

Comment: Code Igniter is written with many PHP 4 idioms (most notably, it passes so many things around with the ampersand it's seems silly sometimes). With that framework, PHP5 is bound to complain about it when you have STRICT warnings enabled.

Comment: Now for specifics... what is the return value of is_loaded(), and then how is $this->_base_classes used later?

Comment: this is how it's used,
$library == '' OR isset($this->_base_classes[$library])

Comment: @ctrahey
previous comment and this one, that's all I know!

/**
* Is Loaded

* A utility function to test if a class is in the self::$_ci_classes array.

* This function returns the object name if the class tested for is loaded,and returns FALSE if it isn't.

* It is mainly used in the form_helper -> _get_validation_object()

*@param  string class being checked for
*@return  mixed class object name on the CI SuperObject or FALSE
*/

public function is_loaded($class)
{
 if (isset($this->_ci_classes[$class]))
 {
  return $this->_ci_classes[$class];
 }
 return FALSE;
}

Comment: Is the line of code in your question one that you wrote, or is it in the framework?

Comment: what version of CI are you using? I'm using 2.1 and I dont get any strict errors...